# Get JSON from a url jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get some json data from this url:

```
https://block.io/api/v2/get_network_fee_estimate/?api_key=3a76-cee6-531b-6f51&amounts=1&to_addresses=2NGWg8QpRxZ3m6wBHpQPW7r1rjL56hE42ht
```

so it would be something like datafeee['data']['estimated_network_fee']
using this:

```
$.getJSON(' https://block.io/api/v2/get_network_fee_estimate/?api_key=3a76-cee6-531b-6f51&amounts='+ simulator_btc +'&to_addresses=2NGWg8QpRxZ3m6wBHpQPW7r1rjL56hE42ht', function(datafee) {
                                  datafeee = datafee;
                              });
```

All I'm getting is a 404 error in the console.

Feel free to try and get that data using javascript /jquery from that url and please show me how.

Note: url doesn't contain any 'private' info

Thank you!

HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/k3gL1g38/1/

Comment: 404 is not found. Echo out the URL, and make sure it's going to the right place

Comment: Since the URL you pasted does not result in 404, I assume you're somehow dynamically assembling the URL and have a mistake in that generation. As suggested above, echo the URL to see that it is being assemble correctly.

Comment: There is most likely a problem with your built http string.

Comment: I would compare the built string against a hard-coded string.

Comment: Could be cross domain issue?

Comment: Error is the following: `{
  "status" : "fail",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "Destination address 2NGWg8QpRxZ3m6wBHpQPW7r1rjL56hE42ht is invalid for Network=BTC."
  }
}`. The api uses strange http-codes. You should check the responses in your browsers network explorer.

Comment: Check this fiddle , I messed up the api keys first time: https://jsfiddle.net/k3gL1g38/1/

Comment: You should really check the network tab. Next error: `Cannot withdraw funds without Network Fee of 0.00092664 BTCTEST. Maximum withdrawable balance is 0.00907336 BTCTEST.`

Comment: @kekub I'm  not interested in that. I'm interested in the estimated_fee so I can calculate the tax in a simulator, error_message is just another field in the 'data'

Comment: @FrankerZ I guess I know what a 404 error is. Please check this fiddle and see it yourself( you can open the 404 link in the console ) https://jsfiddle.net/k3gL1g38/1/

Comment: The API is returning 404. This indicates to jQuery that the request failed. You could abuse the fail callback to get the data: https://jsfiddle.net/k3gL1g38/2/

Comment: @kekub Write your comment as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is returning a 404 error: `Cannot withdraw funds without Network Fee of 0.00092664 BTCTEST. Maximum withdrawable balance is 0.00907336 BTCTEST.`.

You need to attach to the fail event if you want to read the data that the API returned anyways. Pay attention: The fail event will also fire if the url is unreachable or another error occurs.

```js
$.getJSON('https://block.io/api/v2/get_network_fee_estimate/?api_key=3a76-cee6-531b-6f51&amounts=1&to_addresses=2NGWg8QpRxZ3m6wBHpQPW7r1rjL56hE42ht', function(x) {
 // This will never happen
}).fail(function( jqxhr) {
    var response = jqxhr.responseJSON;
    document.querySelector('div').innerText = response.data.estimated_network_fee;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly. My knowledge on js is pretty poor so please help me with the next thing as well:  if I'm doing feex = response.data.estimated_network_fee; , I'm not able to write 'feex' to a div outside the 'fail' function , it takes it as undefined.

Comment: You should try to learn some JavaScript fundamentals first. You are running into a problem caused by the asynchronousness of JavaScript. The code to set the text is called before the code in the fail callback has been executed. See my example for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/k3gL1g38/4/